# If $f(0)=0$ then prove that $|f(z)+f(-z)| \leq 2|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let , $\Delta = B(0,1)$.

If $f:\Delta \rightarrow \Delta$ is holomorphic, and $f(0)=0$, prove that $|f(z)+f(-z)| \leq 2|z|^2$.

**My attempt so far:**

$\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_{2n} z^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_{2n+1} z^{2n+1}$

$\displaystyle f(-z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (-z)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_{2n} z^{2n} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_{2n+1} z^{2n+1}$

Then, $\displaystyle f(z)+f(-z) = 2  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_{2n} (z^2)^n =: 2 g(z^2)$

If $g(\Delta) \subset \Delta$, as $g(0) = 0$, I can invoke Schwarz Lemma and I win. However, I don't know how to prove this. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $g(z)\not \in \Delta $ for some $z\in \Delta$. Then we can take some square root $w\in \Delta$ of $z$ to get 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(f(w)+f(-w)\right) = g(z).
$$
Taking absolute values on the left hand side we get
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2}\left(f(w)+f(-w)\right)\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\left|
f(w)\right|+\left|f(-w)\right|\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1.
$$
This contradicts our assumption that $g(z)\not \in \Delta$. So $g(\Delta)\subseteq \Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Apply Schwarz lemma on $$g(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2z}&\text{ if } z\not=0\\0 &\text{ if } z=0\end{cases}$$

---

Applying Schwarz lemma on $f$ we get , $|f(z)|\le |z|$ for all $z\in \Delta$. Then ,

$$|g(z)|\le \frac{|f(z)|+|f(-z)|}{2|z|}\le \frac{2|z|}{2|z|}=1.$$That is , $g:\Delta \to \Delta$ analytic with $|g(z)|\le 1$ and $g(0)=0$. *So you are able to apply Schwarz lemma on $g$*.

Comment: $|f(z^2)+f(-z^2)| \leq 2 |z|^2$ by Schwarz lemma for $f$ and triangle inequality; and I end up having $2g(z^2) \leq 2|z|^2$, which is what I want. Was that your idea?

Comment: See the edition..I think you will get..

Comment: Awesome. You'd have to prove that $g$ is analytic, but that is fairly easy. Thanks!